# Why are my tags getting flipped?

Tags: support, tags

On [Should you secretly drill your children?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/7712/644), for example, I put the safety tag first and discipline second, but after submitting it reversed the tags.  This isn't really that big a deal, except in some circumstances, like sharing a question, the first tag is used in the title.  While discipline fits, I would consider safety the "primary" tag.

This has happened on my other questions too.  Is there a way to work around it, perhaps by entering my tags in reverse order, or is there some other algorithm going on, like the most popular one being moved first?

Comment: As a side note, this meta question preserved my original tag order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tags are shown in the [order of the tag's popularity on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87508/are-the-tags-shown-in-a-particular-order), apparently.

Others have requested that this feature be changed, to allow users to specify the tag order.  However, the [request appears to have been declined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51157/do-not-order-tags-on-questions-based-popularity-and-keep-them-in-order-specified#comment216433_51160).